# Python: Combining unique values in list of dicts where keys are the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary-comprehension

I'm not sure if I am asking the question in the right way, but this is my issue:

I have a list of dicts in the following format:

```
[
{'user': 'joe', 'IndexUsed': 'a'}, 
{'user': 'joe', 'IndexUsed': 'a'},
{'user': 'joe', 'IndexUsed': 'a'},
{'user': 'joe', 'IndexUsed': 'b'}, 
{'user': 'admin', 'IndexUsed': 'a'}, 
{'user': 'admin', 'IndexUsed': 'c'},
{'user': 'hugo', 'IndexUsed': 'a'},
{'user': 'hugo', 'IndexUsed': 'd'},
...
]
```

I want my final result to look like this:

```
[
{'user': 'joe', 'IndexUsed': ['a', 'b']}, 
{'user': 'admin', 'IndexUsed': ['a', 'c']}, 
{'user': 'hugo', 'IndexUsed': ['a', 'd']},
]
```

In essence, combining/deduplicating the unique fields in `IndexUsed` and reducing them to only one dict per `user`

I have looked into using reducers, dict comprehension, and searched on StackOverflow but I have some trouble finding use cases using strings. The majority of examples I have found are using integers to combine them into a final int/float, but here I rather want to combine it into a single final string. Could you help me understand how to approach this problem?

Comment: So you want the output to remain as a list of dicts, but with the IndexUsed key being consolidated in to a list?

Answer (score 4):

```
from collections import defaultdict


data = [{'IndexUsed': 'a', 'user': 'joe'},
 {'IndexUsed': 'a', 'user': 'joe'},
 {'IndexUsed': 'a', 'user': 'joe'},
 {'IndexUsed': 'b', 'user': 'joe'},
 {'IndexUsed': 'a', 'user': 'admin'},
 {'IndexUsed': 'c', 'user': 'admin'},
 {'IndexUsed': 'a', 'user': 'hugo'},
 {'IndexUsed': 'd', 'user': 'hugo'}]

indexes_used = defaultdict(set)
for d in data:
    indexes_used[d['user']].add(d['IndexUsed'])

result = []
for k, v in indexes_used.items():
    result.append({'user': k, 'IndexUsed': sorted(list(v))})

print(*result)
```

Outputs:

```
{'user': 'joe', 'IndexUsed': ['a', 'b']} {'user': 'admin', 'IndexUsed': ['a', 'c']} {'user': 'hugo', 'IndexUsed': ['a', 'd']}
```

Note: for the unaware, `defaultdict` uses the passed function (`set` in this case) as a factory to create the new missing key corresponding value. So every single key of `indexes_used` *is set* to a `set` filled with the used indexes. Using a `set` also ignores duplicates. In the end the `set` is converted to a sorted list, while creating the required key `IndexUsed`.

Answer (score 1):

If the dictionaries are guaranteed to be grouped together by name, then you could use `itertools.groupby` to process each group of dictionaries separately:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = [
    {'user': 'joe', 'IndexUsed': 'a'},
    {'user': 'joe', 'IndexUsed': 'a'},
    {'user': 'joe', 'IndexUsed': 'a'},
    {'user': 'joe', 'IndexUsed': 'b'},
    {'user': 'admin', 'IndexUsed': 'a'},
    {'user': 'admin', 'IndexUsed': 'c'},
    {'user': 'hugo', 'IndexUsed': 'a'},
    {'user': 'hugo', 'IndexUsed': 'd'},
]

merged_data = [{"user": key, "IndexUsed": list({i: None for i in map(itemgetter("IndexUsed"), group)})} for key, group in groupby(data, key=itemgetter("user"))]
for d in merged_data:
    print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'user': 'joe', 'IndexUsed': ['a', 'b']}
{'user': 'admin', 'IndexUsed': ['a', 'c']}
{'user': 'hugo', 'IndexUsed': ['a', 'd']}
>>>
```

This was just the first thing I came up with, but I don't like it for several reasons. First, like I said, it assumes that the original dictionaries are grouped together by the key `user`. In addition, long list-comprehensions are not readable and should be avoided. The way in which the merged `IndexUsed` list is generated is by creating a temporary dictionary which maps unique entries to `None` (ew, gross - a dictionary is used rather than a set, because sets don't preserve insertion order). It also assumes you're using a certain version of Python 3.x+, where dictionaries are guaranteed to preserve insertion order (you could be more explicit by using `collections.OrderedDict`, but that's one more import). Finally, you shouldn't have to hardcode the `"user"` and `"IndexUsed"` key-literals. Someone please suggest a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this requirement without making use of any libs if you are interested:

```py
arr = [
{'user': 'joe', 'IndexUsed': 'a'}, 
{'user': 'joe', 'IndexUsed': 'a'},
{'user': 'joe', 'IndexUsed': 'a'},
{'user': 'joe', 'IndexUsed': 'b'}, 
{'user': 'admin', 'IndexUsed': 'a'}, 
{'user': 'admin', 'IndexUsed': 'c'},
{'user': 'hugo', 'IndexUsed': 'a'},
{'user': 'hugo', 'IndexUsed': 'd'},
]

global_dict = {}


            
for d in arr:


     if(False if d["user"] in global_dict else True):

            global_dict[d["user"]] = [d["IndexUsed"]]
     else:
            global_dict[d["user"]].append(d["IndexUsed"])
            global_dict[d["user"]] = list(set(global_dict[d["user"]]))
 

print(global_dict)

# Now we get a dict of dicts with key as user and value as an array of distinct IndexUsed values: 
# {
#  'joe': ['b', 'a'],
#  'admin': ['c', 'a'],
#  'hugo': ['d', 'a']
# }



final_list = []

for k,v in global_dict.items():
    final_list.append({"user":k,"IndexUsed":v})


print(final_list)

#Desired Output
# [
#  {'user': 'joe', 'IndexUsed': ['b', 'a']},
#  {'user': 'admin', 'IndexUsed': ['c', 'a']},
#  {'user': 'hugo', 'IndexUsed': ['d', 'a']}
# ]
```

However, if you are a fan of short-liners...
let me minimize @progmatico's awesome defaultdict approach to just these three lines.

```py
from collections import defaultdict


indexes_used = defaultdict(set)
[indexes_used[d['user']].add(d['IndexUsed']) for d in data] # for the side effect
print([{'user': k, 'IndexUsed': sorted(list(v))} for k, v in indexes_used.items()])
```

And it's still readable.

Comment: Thanks, just edited a little bit. I think *working and readable* is good enough. In Python you should never assume you made it in the *most pythonic way*. There may be yet another idiomatic way. Although elegance usually shows for itself, I see too much people worried about being *pythonic*.

Comment: @progmatico, I fully agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

without any external lib:

```
l = [
    {'user': 'joe', 'IndexUsed': 'a'}, 
    {'user': 'joe', 'IndexUsed': 'a'},
    {'user': 'joe', 'IndexUsed': 'a'},
    {'user': 'joe', 'IndexUsed': 'b'}, 
    {'user': 'admin', 'IndexUsed': 'a'}, 
    {'user': 'admin', 'IndexUsed': 'c'},
    {'user': 'hugo', 'IndexUsed': 'a'},
    {'user': 'hugo', 'IndexUsed': 'd'}
]

def combinator(l):
    d = {}
        
    for item in l:
        if(d.get(item['user']) == None):
            d[item['user']] = {item['IndexUsed']}
            pass
        d[item['user']].add(item['IndexUsed'])
        
    return [{'user': key, 'IndexUsed': sorted(value)} for key, value in d.items()]


print(combinator(l))
```